# Fwrite and Fread for Vector return Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, vector, fwrite, fread

I made codes in c++, for encryption and decryption. first code creates an output in vector and then write it in a file by using fwrite, and the second reads that output from the first by using fread.
Here is the snippet of my codes :

1st code :

```
.....
string a;
vector<long long int> c;

cout << "message to be encrypted = ";
cin >> a;   
cout << endl;

cout << "Encrypted message : ";
for (i=0;i<a.size();i++) 
{
    x=(int)a.at(i);
    cout << x << " ";
    c.push_back(powerMod(x,e,n));
}

for (i=0;i<c.size();i++) 
{
    //cout << char(c.at(i));
}
cout << endl;

//Write ciphertext c to a file
FILE * pWrite;
pWrite = fopen ("ciphertext", "w");
fwrite (&c , sizeof(c), 1, pWrite);
fclose (pWrite);
```

The output is :

```
message to be encrypted = test
Encrypted message : 116 101 115 116
```

And then the 2nd code :

```
....
//Read Ciphertext from ciphertext
FILE * pRead2;
pRead2 = fopen ("ciphertext", "r");
fread (&c , sizeof(c), 1, pRead2);
//cout << "ciphertext is " << c << endl;

// Decryption
cout << "Decrypted message : ";
for (i=0;i<c.size();i++) 
{
    cout << powerMod(c.at(i),d,n) << " " ;
}
cout << endl;
```

But it return :

```
Segmentation Fault(Core Dumped)
```

I appreciate any help, since I don't know where is the problem, in the fwrite or in the fread. But I think the problem is in the 2nd, when it tries to read the ciphertext (which is a vector), because if I erase that lines, the program is running perfectly, but without decrypting the message.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a core dump file? If so, gdb will help you

Comment: You cannot store a vector to a file like that. For one, the vector contains a pointer to its data, and the address of this pointer only makes sense in the process in which the vector was created. Try saving the vector's elements. Also, look at [boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you write a *pointer to the vector object instance*, and not the actual vector data. Use

```
fwrite (&c[0], sizeof(vector<long long int>::value_type), c.size(), pWrite);
```

Also remember that `sizeof(c)` returns the size of the *vector object instance*, not the number of items in the vector.

You have a similar problem when reading the vector. You have to do it one by one in a loop, pushing the items on to the vector again.

---

With C++ there are simpler ways of doing this, if you learn to use the [C++ I/O stream library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) and some nice [standard algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) and use [iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator).

To write a vector to a file:

```
std::ofstream os{"ciphertext", std::ios::out};

std::copy(std::begin(c), std::end(c),
          std::ostream_iterator<long long int>(os));
```

And to read from the file:

```
std::ifstream is{"ciphertext", std::ios::in};

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<long long int>(is),
          std::istream_iterator<long long int>(),
          std::back_inserter(c));
```

There's actually an even *simpler* way to read from a file into a vector:

```
std::ifstream is{"ciphertext", std::ios::in};

std::vector<long long int> c(std::istream_iterator<long long int>(is),
                             std::istream_iterator<long long int>());
```

This relies on the [`std::vector` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) taking two iterators as arguments.

---

If you don't want to use text files, but binary files, you unfortunately have to loop manually and write/read the data, i.e. you manually have to do what `std::copy` does for you.

Something like this to write the data:

```
std::ofstream os{"ciphertext", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary};

for (const auto& value : c)
    os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&value), sizeof(value));
```

And like this to read it:

```
std::ifstream is{"ciphertext", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary};

long long int value:
while (is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), sizeof(value)))
    c.push_back(value);
```

If you don't have the C++11 [range-based `for` loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Range-based_for_loop) (used in the writing example above), use a normal classic iteration `for` loop:

```
std::vector<long long int>::const_iterator i;
for (i = c.begin(); i != c.end(); ++i)
    os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&(*i)), sizeof(*i));
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the 2nd solution, and the error is ‘istream_operator’ is not a member of ‘std’, I googled, and tried include <iterator> but still the error exist.

Comment: @dulipat `istream_iterator` not `istream_operator`:)

Comment: Good lord, thanks for correcting me..:) Ok, I ran it again, there's something wrong with the decryption part. 
The output of encryption : 
Encrypted message : 104 97 104 97 104 97 
Meanwhile the output of decryption : 
Decrypted message = -504

Do you think the error is in the decryption algorithm? or when it try to read the file, the vector was not correctly build?

Thanks.

Comment: @dulipat If the file reading works or not is very easy to check, just before writing the vector to the file you print it out (as is), then just after reading it back in you do the same. If there's a difference there's some problem with the file handling. Otherwise there's a problem with the decryption.

Comment: I checked it, and I think there is something wrong with file handling, before writing the file, the print out is : {1 2 3 4}, vector with 4 elements, but after reading the file, the print out is : {1234}, just 1 concatenated element.

Comment: @dulipat It might be that it's written as text instead of binary. You can easily check that by simply opening the file in a text editor. If it is, then you have to use e.g. `std::ostream_iterator<long long int>(os, " ")` when writing the output. *If* it's okay to use text files instead. If you want raw binary files then give me a holler and I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: now everything is fine, for now I think it's okay to use text files, if in the future I want raw binary files, what should I do. Thank you very much for the help, :)

Comment: `vector<long long int>::size_type` is a type, not the size of the elements, which I think is what you intended. Correct would be:

`fwrite (&c[0], sizeof(long long int), c.size(), pWrite);`

Comment: @davmac It was just the `sizeof` I missed, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, no! you are still using size_type. You want the size of the value_type. Also your arguments in the wrong order - the size of the element should come before the number of elements.